# Phoenix Elixir Post JSON with association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to POST for association one to many with JSON in Phoenix Elixir. There are many examples on the web, but I have not seen one example with one to many association. How can I pass the parameters for contact in the controller?

The schema for `Costumer` is

```
schema "customers" do
  field :email, :string
  field :name, :string
  has_many :contacts, App.Customers.Contact

  timestamps()
end

@doc false
def changeset(customer, attrs \\ %{}) do
  customer
  |> cast(attrs, [:name, :email])
  |> validate_required([:name, :email])
  |> unique_constraint(:email)
end
```

The schema for `Contact` is

```
schema "contacts" do
  field :phone, :string
  belongs_to :customers, App.Customers.Customer,  foreign_key: :customer_id

  timestamps()
end

@doc false
def changeset(contact, attrs \\ %{}) do
  contact
  |> cast(attrs, [:phone])
  |> validate_required([:phone])
end
```

This is the controller:

```
def create(conn, %{"email" => email, "name" => name, "phone" => phone} = customer_params) do
  with {:ok, %Customer{} = customer} <- Customers.create_customer(customer_params) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
    |> put_resp_header("location", Routes.customer_path(conn, :show, customer))
    |> render("show.json", customer: customer)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you having an issue with Ecto and the associations, or is your issue with how to get the JSON params?

Comment: I think both, in the contextual module I have:     def create_customer(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %Customer{}
    |> Customer.changeset(attrs)
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(:contacts, with: &Contact.changeset/2)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Customer`, change the `changeset` function to:

```
def changeset(customer, attrs \\ %{}) do
  customer
  |> cast(attrs, [:name, :email])
  |> validate_required([:name, :email])
  |> unique_constraint(:email)
  |> cast_assoc(:contacts)
end
```

And then pass the parameters like this:

```
%{"name" => "john doe", "email" => "example@example.com", "contacts" => [
  %{"phone" => "555-555-555"},
  %{"phone" => "555-555-555"}
]}
```

With this, the `create_customer` function in the context doesn't need to be changed:

```
def create_customer(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %Customer{}
  |> Customer.changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```

Keep in mind, though, that in order to update a `Customer`, you would need to first preload contacts.

You can find more information in the [cast_assoc documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3).

Comment: thanks, but I have the error  no function clause matching in AppWeb.CustomerController.create/2 .    # 1
    %Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, before_send: [#Function<1.112466771/1 in Plug.Logger.call/2> .        # 2
    %{"email" => "l", "name" => "l", "phone" => "9"}

Comment: You can remove the pattern matching in your `AppWeb.CustomerController.create/2` definition: `def create(conn, customer_params) do ....`.